# Finding time elapsed within a grouped variable in R

Tags: r, dataframe, datetime, time, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks something like this:

```
tbl <- data.frame( S1 = c(7056, 7101.1, 5145, 2198, 7106.1, 7167.1, 7141.1, 7771.1), file = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2) datetime = c("2021-02-10 14:25:44 UTC", "2021-02-10 14:25:54 UTC", "2021-02-10 14:26:04 UTC", "2021-02-10 14:26:14 UTC", "2021-02-10 14:27:44 UTC" "2021-02-10 14:27:54 UTC" "2021-02-10 14:28:04 UTC" "2021-02-10 14:28:14 UTC")
```

I would like to find the time elapsed for each file. Basically grouping by "file" and subtracting the most recent date-time from the oldest date-time.

The output should look something like this:
output <- data.frame(file = c(1,2), time_elapsed = c(00:02:00,00:04:10))

My issue is I don't know how to select the most recent and oldest time to subtract.

Answer (score 0):

use `first` and `last` functions from `dplyr` library which return the first and last values respectively in the group.  I have added an additional line for arranging the data, in case it isn't which you can skip as per use case.  Follow this syntax-

```
library(dplyr)
tbl %>% group_by(file) %>%
  arrange(file, datetime) %>%
  summarise(time_elapsed = difftime(last(datetime), first(datetime)))

# A tibble: 2 x 2
   file time_elapsed
  <dbl> <drtn>      
1     1 30 secs     
2     2 30 secs
```

your `tbl` data

```
tbl <- structure(list(S1 = c(7056, 7101.1, 5145, 2198, 7106.1, 7167.1, 
7141.1, 7771.1), file = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), datetime = c("2021-02-10 14:25:44 UTC", 
"2021-02-10 14:25:54 UTC", "2021-02-10 14:26:04 UTC", "2021-02-10 14:26:14 UTC", 
"2021-02-10 14:27:44 UTC", "2021-02-10 14:27:54 UTC", "2021-02-10 14:28:04 UTC", 
"2021-02-10 14:28:14 UTC")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-8L))

> tbl
      S1 file                datetime
1 7056.0    1 2021-02-10 14:25:44 UTC
2 7101.1    1 2021-02-10 14:25:54 UTC
3 5145.0    1 2021-02-10 14:26:04 UTC
4 2198.0    1 2021-02-10 14:26:14 UTC
5 7106.1    2 2021-02-10 14:27:44 UTC
6 7167.1    2 2021-02-10 14:27:54 UTC
7 7141.1    2 2021-02-10 14:28:04 UTC
8 7771.1    2 2021-02-10 14:28:14 UTC
```